# Comparing the number of the current chapter with another one

Tags: macros, conditionals

I am typesetting a book (using the `book` class) which consists of a large number of small chapters and I wish to be able to freely change the order of the chapters. Since there are cross-references, I wish to have a macro `\comparechapter` which does this: if a certain certain chapter has a label called, say, `cha:pi` then if I type `\comparechapter{cha:pi}` within another chapter, I get:

- “was seen on chapter […]” if the number of the current chapter is higher than the number the chapter containg the `cha:pi` label;
- “will be seen on chapter […]” otherwise.

How can I do this? I know that I can get the number of the current chapter using `\value{chapter}`. What I lack is the knowledge about how to obtain the number of the chapter containing the `cha:pi` label.

Comment: Have you tried simply adding a label to the chapter (so right after the `\chapter` command)? That's how it works with sections

Comment: My guess is that that's a good suggestion, but I don't get it. And, yes, I've put `\label{cha:pi}`right after the `\chapter` command.

Comment: It's better to place `\label` tag inside the `\chapter` tag, e.g., `\chapter{test\label{labelname}`

Comment: @MadyYuvi Thank you. I did not know that.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos You're welcome, may I know whether your problem fixed?

Comment: I would try to do that with `cleveref`  and  `etoolbox` (to compare chapter numbers). The problem is  to have  a test  to choose a string between *was* and *will be*.

Comment: @MadyYuvi No. I am feeling quite embarassed, because it is obvious to you that I have all the information that I need to fix the problem, but I simply have no idea about how to do it.

Comment: hmmm, is it possible to post a `MWE`? else post your `log` file...

Comment: @MadyYuvi No need. I finally got it: `\newcommand\comparechapter[1]{\ifthenelse{\value{chapter}>\ref{#1}}{was seen on chapter
    \ref{#1}}{will be seen on chapter \ref{#1}}}`. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos You xn nanswer your own question here so it does not remain on the unanswered queue attracting attention.

Comment: @EthanBolker Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, I was able to find an answer to my own question. Here is how I did it:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand\comparechapter[1]{\ifthenelse{\value{chapter}>\ref{#1}}{%
    was seen on chapter \ref{#1}}{will be seen on chapter \ref{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1\label{cha:A}}
This \comparechapter{cha:B}.
\chapter{Chapter 2\label{cha:B}}
This \comparechapter{cha:A}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah yes, \ifthenelse automatically replaces \ref with \getrefnumber (refcount package).